# replace a string in the file is overwriting everything

Tags: regex, file, tcl

I have a tcl file named test.tcl
It has the following information

```
TimePlace=12:04:East
Work=None
```

Now I want to replace `TimePlace` with `CreateTime` so that content becomes

```
CreateTime=12:04:East
```

I did following but somehow the old contents are getting deleted. `Work=None` disappears.

```
set filename [open "test.tcl" "w"]
regsub -all "TimePlace" $filename "CreateTime" filename
close $filename
```

I am not able to figure out what am I missing. New to TCL. Can you please provide some direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the first problem is that you are opening the file for writing with `open "test.tcl" "w"`. Doing that will erase everything from the file. For starters, I would advise opening the file for reading and writing separately.

But that's not the only issue with this part, `filename` is the name of the channel (you can say it's like a medium name through which tcl will communicate to the file) and not the contents of the file itself.

```
set filename [open "test.tcl" "r"] ;# Create a channel named 'filename' for reading
set contents [read $filename]      ;# Read the contents of the file and store in contents
close $filename                    ;# Close the file since we don't need to read it more than that
```

After that, you can replace:

```
regsub -all "TimePlace" $contents "CreateTime" contents
```

This will replace all the occurrences of `TimePlace` in the file with `CreateTime`.

---

Note that the above replacement doesn't use regular expressions, so you might as well use `string map` instead to achieve the same results:

```
set contents [string map {TimePlace CreateTime} $contents]
```

---

You then open the file for writing:

```
set filename [open "test.tcl" "w"] ;# Open the file for writing and erasing all contents
puts $filename $contents           ;# Write '$contents' to the file
close $filename                    ;# Close the file.
```

Comment: Also, if you are reading a long file, you might want to read line by line using a loop and `gets` instead of reading the whole file in one go with `read`.

Comment: Yes, i figured it out later that i was writing the file directly. Thanks :)